# Why "wonder woman" and not "wonderwoman"?

Tags: pop-culture

It's kind of pedantic question perhaps, or maybe if the reason I'm not getting the point is not that English is my second language, perhaps you can call it a feminist outcry, but regardless:

Why is there a space in "Wonder Woman" but none in "Superman"?

Imao, both of these are the same thing, more or less, only designed for presumably different marketing demands.

Or maybe it is just beauty of shorter words.

Comment: Pedantic or trivial?

Comment: I suspect perhaps it’s simply that the alliteration comes out more clearly with a space. Though that still leaves the hyphen in Spider-Man unaccounted for…

Comment: It's a decision made by those who coined the terms, before even I was born (and that's a long time ago).  Choosing such a name is something of an artistic decision, and (at least at the time) it needed no rationalization.

Comment: (Do note that "Superman" was coined by George Bernard Shaw in 1903, and he borrowed the term from Friedrich Nietzsche's "Übermensch".  So the term originated German.)

Comment: Neither is a *word* but a *name* (or title). Names can follow any pattern you wish. That's why there is a villain called *Thanos*, which is not a word at all. *Why* did the creator of the character put a space in their name? You'd have to ask them . . .

Comment: I always wondered about Superman, Spider-Man, and Bat Man.  Are they avoiding some sort of copyright infringement?

Comment: @GEdgar Who is Bat Man? I only know of Batman. (And [Batman bin Suparman](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=5), of course.)

Answer (score 3):

It's only natural that whoever creates a superhero name should get to decide whether to use a space (as in [*Wonder Woman*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wonder_Woman)) or nothing (as in [*Superman*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman)) between the first word and the second. Does this necessarily mean that creating a superhero name is purely arbitrary and is not bound by any rules of English? I don't think so.

Nor do I think it's got anything to do with treating 'man' differently from 'woman', because we have [*Superwoman*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superwoman), [*Wonder Man*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wonder_Man) and [*Batwoman*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batwoman)  instead of *Super Woman*, *Wonderman* and *Bat Woman*, respectively.

I for one think that it's got to do with the length of the first word. For example, *Wonder* has six letters, which might feel a bit too long to combine with the following word in a single word ?*Wonderwoman* or ?*Wonderman*. *Super* has five letters, which might feel short enough to combine with the following word in a single word [*Superman*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman) or [*Superwoman*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superwoman). And *Bat* has only three letters, which might feel short enough to combine with the following word in a single word [*Batman*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman) or [*Batwoman*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batwoman).

That said, arbitrariness cannot be entirely excluded when it comes to inserting a hyphen between the two words. For example, *Spider*, has the same number of letters as *Wonder*, but [*Spider-Man*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man) and [*Spider-Woman*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Woman) do not have a space but a hyphen in between. A shorter word *Man* is also connected with *Bat* via a hyphen in [*Man-Bat*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-Bat).

Except for the use of a hyphen, it's got to do with the length of the first word rather than with the second word being *man* or *woman*.

Comment: With your logic, Man-bat should have been called Manbat.

Comment: @TymekWojnarowski You got me!

Comment: but apart from that, the two first paragraphs from your answer is what I would agree with.

Comment: @TymekWojnarowski I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is also used to distinghuish the characters. For [example](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2012/07/spider-man.html):

> Spider-Man’s name has a hyphen because Stan Lee, who created the comic
>   character with Steve Ditko, apparently wanted to distinguish him from
>   Superman.

Answer (score 0):

When the character was first conceived, her proposed name was actually "*Suprema - The Wonder Woman*". This was replaced with simply "Wonder Woman," which was an *existing term* [defined in the dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/wonder+woman) as "a woman who can be a successful wife and have a professional career at the same time" and in popular use during the 1940s at the time of her inception. So the main reason her name was a two-word term is that it was originally more of her **title** than her name (like *Robin the Boy Wonder*).

Also, it is notable that there was an acknowledged trend during the *silver age of comics* to give comic book characters *alliterative names* (eg **P**eter **P**arker, **B**ruce **B**anner, **B**illy **B**atson etc). Although Wonder Woman and Superman were from the earlier *golden age* of comics, DC arguably started this trend with Lois Lane and Lex Luther in Superman. *Wonder Woman* continued this trend, perhaps intentionally.

Had *Wonder Woman* been named "Wonderwoman" they would not have been able to stylise it as *WW*, or create the recognisable logo that incorporates the two 'W's (although this was not created at her debut and did not appear until 1982).

Comment: But Peter Parker, Bruce Banner, and Billy Batson are all human alter egos, whereas Wonder Woman is the superhero whose human alter ego is Diana Prince. Just saying.

Comment: @JK2 Green Goblin? Silver Surfer? Miss Marvel? Silk Spectre? And as I mentioned, many of those came in the silver age - Wonder Woman was golden age. Lois Lane and Lex Luther did not have alter egos.